# What happened to COPR?

Tags: centos, fedora, rhel

There used to be a Fedora build system known as [COPR](https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/) where devs could build for a variety of yum based distros.

I knew that FedoraHosted was disappearing to be replaced by Pagure, but what of COPR?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a temporary external hosting outage.

Comment: Happy for you to close it - wasn't sure where else to ask, wasn't aware of scheduled maintenance, nor where to find that that was in fact the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[COPR](https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/) was in scheduled [maintenance](http://status.fedoraproject.org/) right [during this moment in time in 2017](https://lists.fedoraproject.org/archives/list/devel-announce@lists.fedoraproject.org/thread/TSWJRNGBJ2WBHC35RYVLK5S2AOZIVGJ4/). In general, it's running at https://copr.fedoraproject.org/.